# I am unable to install expressJS in windows

Tags: node.js, express

[this is the command i used to try and install express locally.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEQMz.png)

but the cursor keeps on rotating endlessly. I cant understand whats the problem. I am new to Node and its already testing my patience. Please help.
Comment if you need additional information.

Comment: Try typing `npm install express --save` from another directory and see what happens

Comment: no improvement yet. still the cursor keeps on rotating endlessly. any other suggestions? tried restarting cmd and even the whole computer....

Comment: Sorry, I meant `npm install -g express`. It should install express globally.

Comment: Ok. global installation did help but now it shows this different error message saying 'cannot find module 'bytes' '. Any insights?

Comment: What does 'help' mean? Could you install express finally?

Comment: Suddenly,  everything is running normally. Thanks for the help...